# How to prevent safari font size increasing behavior?

Tags: css, safari, viewport

Safari increases font size from 9-18px to 18px at high width(about 2880px). Does anyone know how to prevent this behavior?

To reproduce:

1. Look at "About" or "Products" or "For Teams" on the stackoverflow header, right after logo, via safari inspector
2. Font size of any menu item is 13px
3. Press ctrl - "+" (or cmd - "+" on MacOS) to maximum (width will be about 2800px or higher)
4. Font size of any menu item is 18px